# What's on your mind?

Tags: pronouns

Can this sentence be correct?

> Jack: There is something on my mind.
>
> Amanda: I don't know what **it's** on your mind.

Or should it be "what's on your mind" instead?

Comment: Yes, it should be (short for 'what is on your mind', of course).

Answer (score 3):

The words *it* and *what* are both pronouns. They can't occupy the same position in a sentence.

In the sentence above:

> I don't know _____ is on your mind.

*What* works best here—as far as natural, conversational speech.

You can imagine using *it* and walking about the past tense, when the subject of "the thing on the person's mind" is now known:

> I didn't know it was on your mind. You should have told me.

You would have to add an extra clause to use *what* and *it* together. This sentence is unnecessarily complex, though, and I wouldn't recommend using it.

> I don't know *what it is* **that** is on your mind.